# Hide and Show ALL markers

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dictionary, google-maps-api-3, markers

I am building a map which uses angular to call and set the data on to the web page and google map.

This is my first big project using angular and I have it almost working as I envisioned. I would like to add additional functionality to the site to make it more user friendly.

[View the working code.](http://portlandstreetcarbars.com/streetcar-bars-map/app/)

[View code on github.](https://github.com/thorney29/streetcar-map-app)

I've set up two buttons to hide or show all markers, but I been getting the errors clearMarkers, showMarkers, and allSetMap not defined. Onclick, I need these buttons to be able to:

Hide all markers except for the marker with the info window open
Show all markers
I would also like to add code to remove the polyline and restore all markers to original state when the user clicks the "clear directions" button, one of the selections in the top bar of images, or the hide/show markers buttons.

Any help or direction you could provide is very much appreciated! The simpler the code, advice, direction the better as I am obviously a still a beginner. Forks encouraged. I really want to learn this and code correctly. Any guidance is truly appreciated.

This is the html code for the data and map:

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="mapApp" lang="en">
<head>
<meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Map || Portland Streetcar Bars</title>
<meta name="description" content="Map of Portland's Eastside Streetcar Bars">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<!-- Place favicon.ico and apple-touch-icon.png in the root directory    -->
<!-- build:css(.) styles/vendor.css -->
<!-- bower:css -->

<!-- endbower -->
<!-- endbuild -->
<!-- build:css(.tmp) styles/main.css -->

<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../../styles/map-styles.css"> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../styles/mapAppStyles.css">
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="../../styles/waitMe.css"><!--  
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css"> -->  
<script src="../../scripts/lib/modernizr-2.5.3.js"></script>
<script src="../../scripts/modernizr.custom.js"></script>

<script src="//use.typekit.net/kgp0loa.js"></script>
<script>try{Typekit.load();}catch(e){}</script>
<link rel="icon" 
  type="image/png" 
  href="http://portlandstreetcarbars.com/favicons/favicon.ico">

<!-- endbuild -->
</head>
<body>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>
  <p class="browsehappy">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
<![endif]-->

<!-- Add your site or application content here -->
     <!--  Menu Header  -->
<section class="module parallax parallax-1-inner">
<div class="container">
<header>
  <nav id="dl-menu" class="dl-menuwrapper">
      <button class="dl-trigger">Open Menu</button>
      <ul class="navMenu dl-menu">
        <li><a class="hvr-shutter-out-horizontal" href="/">HOME</a>  </li>
        <li><a class="hvr-shutter-out-horizontal" href="/streetcar-bars-list/">BAR LIST</a></li>
        <li><a class="hvr-shutter-out-horizontal" id="current" href="#">MAP</a></li>
        <li><a class="hvr-shutter-out-horizontal" href="/streetcar-bars-crawls/">CRAWLS</a></li>
        <li><a class="hvr-shutter-out-horizontal" href="/streetcar-bars-join/">CONTACT</a></li>
      </ul>
   </nav>
   <div class="clear"></div>
   <div class="header-inner">Portland<span> Streetcar Bars</span></div>
  <div class="inner-eastside-font-effect"><em>Eastside</em></div>
</header> 
</div>
</section>
<div class="clear"></div>
  <section class="module parallax parallax-2">
    <div class="container">
     <h2>Get Directions to Your Next Stop</h2>
     </div>
</section>  
<div ng-view=""></div> 

<div class="clear"></div>
<section class="module parallax parallax-2">
    <div class="container">
      <h2>Featured Stops on the Portland Streetcar</h2>
     </div>
</section>  


 <!-- build:js(.) scripts/oldieshim.js -->
 <!--[if lt IE 9]>
 <script src="bower_components/es5-shim/es5-shim.js"></script>
 <script src="bower_components/json3/lib/json3.js"></script>
 <![endif]-->
 <!-- endbuild -->
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCdOS0Bctn6co9d2ZaecN-LNrU5yi3eoXQ&sensor=true&libraries=places,drawing,geometry"></script>
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- build:js(.) scripts/vendor.js -->
 <!-- bower:js -->
 <script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
 <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
 <script src="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
 <script src="bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js"></script>
 <script src="bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js"></script>
 <script src="bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js"></script>
 <script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
 <script src="bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
 <script src="bower_components/angular-touch/angular-touch.js"></script>
 <script src="bower_components/angular-ui-map/ui-map.js"></script>
 <script src="bower_components/angular-ui-utils/ui-utils.js"></script>

 <!-- endbower -->
 <!-- endbuild -->

    <!-- build:js({.tmp,app}) scripts/scripts.js -->

<script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/controllers/controllers.js"></script>      
<script src="scripts/directives/directives.js"></script> 

    <!-- endbuild -->

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="../../scripts/waitMe.js"></script> 
<script src="../../scripts/jquery.dlmenu.js"></script>

<script>
  $(function(){
      var url = window.location.href; 
      $(".navMenu a").each(function() {
          if(url == (this.href)) { 
              $(this).closest("a").addClass("current");
          }
      });
  });
  (function(){
      var parallax = document.querySelectorAll(".parallax"),
        speed = 0.35;
    window.onscroll = function(){
        [].slice.call(parallax).forEach(function(el,i){
          var windowYOffset = window.pageYOffset,
            elBackgrounPos = "0 " + (windowYOffset * speed) + "px";  
          el.style.backgroundPosition = elBackgrounPos;
      });
    };
  })();
  $(function(){
    // none, bounce, rotateplane, stretch, orbit, 
    // roundBounce, win8, win8_linear or ios
    var current_effect = 'bounce'; // 
    function run_waitMe(effect){
    $('#spinHere').waitMe({
      //none, rotateplane, stretch, orbit, roundBounce, win8, 
      //win8_linear, ios, facebook, rotation, timer, pulse, 
      //progressBar, bouncePulse or img
      effect: 'bounce',

      //place text under the effect (string).
      text: 'Getting Directions',

      //background for container (string).
      bg: 'rgba(255,255,255,0.7)',

      //color for background animation and text (string).
      color: '#000',

      //change width for elem animation (string).
      sizeW: '',

      //change height for elem animation (string).
      sizeH: '',

      // url to image
      source: ''

      });
    }  
  });

  $(function() {
    $( '#dl-menu' ).dlmenu({
      animationClasses : { classin : 'dl-animate-in-3', classout : 'dl-animate-out-3' }
    });
  });
</script>
```

Here is my controller code. It is a mess, but it works for the most part, except for the issues I mentioned above.

```
'use strict';

 var markers = [];
 var mapApp = angular.module('mapControllers', []);
 mapApp.controller('ListController', function ($scope, $http) {
 $http.get('scripts/bars.json').
 success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    //this happens if everything works
    $scope.bars = data;
    $scope.markers = [];
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    var myLatlng100 = new google.maps.LatLng(45.523007, -122.657890);
    var mapOptions = {
            center: myLatlng100,
            styles: [{"featureType":"landscape.natural","elementType":"geometry.fill","stylers":[{"visibility":"on"},{"color":"#e0efef"}]},{"featureType":"poi","elementType":"geometry.fill","stylers":[{"visibility":"on"},{"hue":"#1900ff"},{"color":"#c0e8e8"}]},{"featureType":"road","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"lightness":100},{"visibility":"simplified"}]},{"featureType":"road","elementType":"labels","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"transit.line","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"visibility":"on"},{"lightness":700}]},{"featureType":"water","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"color":"#7dcdcd"}]}],
            zoom: 15,
            draggable: false,
            scrollwheel: false,
            disableDoubleClickZoom: true,
            zoomControl: false             
    };
    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
     // Create a renderer for directions and bind it to the map.
    var rendererOptions = {
            map: $scope.map
    };
    var directionsDisplay;
    var directionsService;
    directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer(rendererOptions);
    $scope.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);
    directionsDisplay.setMap($scope.map);

    $scope.openInfoWindow = function(e, selectedMarker){
        e.preventDefault();
        google.maps.event.trigger(selectedMarker, 'click');
    }; 
    var createMarker = function(bar){
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: $scope.map,
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(bar.lat, bar.lng),
            title: bar.name
        });

        marker.content = '<div class="contentString"><img src="' + 
        bar.image +
        '"><br/>'+ 
        bar.address +
        ' ' +  
        '<br /><button id="spinner" class="button" onclick="getDir('+bar.lat+', '+bar.lng+')">Get Directions</button>' +
        '</div>';
        marker.image = bar.image;

        google.maps.event.addListener(bar, 'click', function(){
            infoWindow.setContent('<a class="info-window" href="' + bar.url + '">' +'<h3 class="info-window" >' + bar.name + '</h3>' + '</a>' +  marker.content);
            infoWindow.open($scope.map, marker);
        });
          google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(){
            infoWindow.setContent('<a class="info-window" href="' + bar.url + '">' +'<h3 class="info-window" >' + bar.name + '</h3>' + '</a>' +  marker.content);
            infoWindow.open($scope.map, marker);
        });
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragstart', function() {
            disableMovement(true);
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function() {
            disableMovement(false);
        });         

        $scope.markers.push(marker);
     };  

    $scope.setAllMap = function(map) {
        for (var i = 0; i < $scope.bars.length; i++){
          createMarker($scope.bars[i]);
        }  
    }
    $scope.setAllMap(map); 

    $scope.clearMarkers = function(map) {
        setAllMap(null);
     }
    $(".hideit").on("click", function(map){
           $scope.clearMarkers(); 
       });

    $("#clearPanel").on("click", function(map){
            document.getElementById("panel").innerHTML = " ";
            $('h3.map').show();
            $('#clearPanel').hide();
      });

console.log($scope.bars);
}).
error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
  console.log("Did not compute");
});
});   

function disableMovement(disable) {
var mapOptions;
if (disable) {
    mapOptions = {
        draggable: false,
        scrollwheel: false,
        disableDoubleClickZoom: true,
        zoomControl: false
    };
} else {
    mapOptions = {
        draggable: true,
        scrollwheel: true,
        disableDoubleClickZoom: false,
        zoomControl: true
    };
}
map.setOptions(mapOptions);
}
function getDir(lat,lng,markers,map) {
 run_waitMe();
 document.getElementById("panel").innerHTML = " ";
// If the browser supports the Geolocation API
    if (typeof navigator.geolocation == "undefined") {
      $("#error").text("Your browser doesn't support the Geolocation API");
      return;
    }
     // Save the positions' history
     var path = [];
     navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {       //This gets the
        // Create the map
         var myOptions = {
            styles: [{"featureType":"landscape.natural","elementType":"geometry.fill","stylers":[{"visibility":"on"},{"color":"#e0efef"}]},{"featureType":"poi","elementType":"geometry.fill","stylers":[{"visibility":"on"},{"hue":"#1900ff"},{"color":"#c0e8e8"}]},{"featureType":"road","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"lightness":100},{"visibility":"simplified"}]},{"featureType":"road","elementType":"labels","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"transit.line","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"visibility":"on"},{"lightness":700}]},{"featureType":"water","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"color":"#7dcdcd"}]}],
            zoom: 15,
            draggable: false,
            scrollwheel: false,
            disableDoubleClickZoom: false,
            zoomControl: true,
            center : path[0],
            mapTypeId : google.maps.MapTypeId.TRANSIT
          };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);

        var latitude = position.coords.latitude;                       //users current
        var longitude = position.coords.longitude;                    
        var start = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);     //Creates variable for map coordinates
           //location
           path.push(new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude));
             // Creates the polyline object
           var polyline = new google.maps.Polyline({
            map: map,
            path: path,
            strokeColor: '#0000FF',
            strokeOpacity: 0.7,
            strokeWeight: 1
           });

        var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
        var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
        directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
        directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById('panel'));

        var request = {
          origin: start,
          destination: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
          travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.TRANSIT
        };
        // Removes the overlays from the map, but keeps them in the array
        function clearOverlays() {
          if (markersArray) {
            for (i in markersArray) {
              markersArray[i].setMap(null);
            }
          }
        }             
        directionsService.route(request, function (response, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
               directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
                $('.waitMe').hide();
                $('h3.map').hide();
                $('#clearPanel').show();
                }
        });
  });
}

// none, bounce, rotateplane, stretch, orbit, 
// roundBounce, win8, win8_linear or ios
var current_effect = 'bounce'; // 

function run_waitMe(effect){
$('#spinHere').waitMe({
    //none, rotateplane, stretch, orbit, roundBounce, win8, 
    //win8_linear, ios, facebook, rotation, timer, pulse, 
    //progressBar, bouncePulse or img
    effect: 'bounce',

    //place text under the effect (string).
    text: 'Getting Directions',

    //background for container (string).
    bg: 'rgba(255,255,255,0.7)',

    //color for background animation and text (string).
    color: '#000',

    //change width for elem animation (string).
    sizeW: '',

    //change height for elem animation (string).
    sizeH: '',

    // url to image
    source: ''

    });
}
```

Comment: Where is `setAllMap()` defined?

Comment: Sorry - that was mistakenly deleted during formatting. I added it back -- it's above the clearMarkers and showMarkers functions.

Comment: @MattHerbstritt: This question mentions errors and additional code to be added, so it doesn't fit on Code Review.

Comment: Sooooo. I've posted all of the code here. Can anyone see what is causing the problem? I am 99% the problem is a scope issue. But I don't know how to fix it. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: @MattHerbstritt Please read [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/5777) so as to avoid misdirecting users again. Thanks.

Comment: @Jamal Yeah I know that's why I said she should get a working demo together first. I meant working as in 'code that works' not as in a 'demo that works to illustrate not working code'. Apologies if I didn't make that clear enough.

Answer (score 0):

Your `setAllMap()` function only exists on the `$scope` object, yet you try to call it as a global function. This maybe one reason why you are getting errors.

```
// the `map` argument is unused and is thus redundant
$scope.setAllMap = function(map) {
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.bars.length; i++){
          createMarker($scope.bars[i]);
    }  
}

// passing map does nothing
$scope.setAllMap(map); 

$scope.clearMarkers = function(map) {
    // this only exists on the $scope object
    // so this is why you will get 'setAllMap is undefined'

    // try changing it to $scope.setAllMap()

    // Also, null does nothing
    setAllMap(null);


}
```